# Error binding mariadb nodejs docker-compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am using docker-compose to create a MariaDB/NodeJS:

```
version: '3'
services: 
    app:
        image: node:alpine
        volumes:
          - ./:/app
        working_dir: /app
        environment:
          NODE_ENV: development
        ports:
          - 3001:3001
        command: npm run dev
    mysql_database:
        image: mariadb:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        expose:
          - 3306
        volumes:
          - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql:rw
          - ./database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
```

The node.js app and mysql server work properly (I can connect to they independely: nodejs--> localhost:3001 and MySQL WorkBrench pointing to localhost:3306), **but the connection between the 2 sevices are not working**. 
Show error:  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
NodeJS applicacion require('mysql'):

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({

connectionLimit: 10,
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '1234',
database: 'biologia',
port: '3306',
```

All this work fine without using docker-compose or deploying mysql docker and run in local (without docker) nodejs poiting to mysql docker.

Comment: try to change `host: 'localhost'` to `host: "mysql_database"`

Comment: You are a completly genius. Really thanks bro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers have no idea about what `localhost` is. Or better say localhost is always the container itself but not your host PC.

Use container name to access it with `docker-compose`.

In your case DB container named `mysql_database`.

Change:

`host: 'localhost'`

to

`host: 'mysql_database',`

when try access from another (`app`) container.